# Increasing the speed of (or an alternative to) RegionPlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I want to include the some region plots in a `Manipulate` structure, however the rendering is almost prohibitively slow. The code is

```
ClearAll[regions, rplot]
r:regions[n_Integer, o_Integer] := r = Apply[And, 
    Subsets[Table[(#1 - Cos[t])^2 + (#2 - Sin[t])^2 <= 1, {t, 2 Pi/n, 
       2 Pi, 2 Pi/n}], {o}], {1}] &
r:rplot[n_Integer, o_Integer] := r = Show[{RegionPlot[
     Evaluate[regions[n, o][x, y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PlotRangePadding -> .1, 
     Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 100], 
    Graphics[Table[Circle[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 1], {t, 2 Pi/n, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n}]]}]
```

Which produces graphics like

```
GraphicsGrid[{{rplot[3, 2], rplot[5, 3]}, {rplot[7, 2], rplot[4, 1]}}]
```

[image: circles from above!]

The above takes about 40 seconds to calculate and render on my computer.
Can anyone suggest a way to get similar quality graphics more quickly?

---

Note 1: I've memoized the graphics object so that doesn't need to recalculate it each time in my demonstration - but it's too slow even the first time.
Note 2: I'm happy with rasterized images, so maybe a flood fill type solution would be an option...
Note 3: I need something like `Manipulate[
 rplot[n, o], {n, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{o, 1}, 
  Range[1, (n + 1)/2], ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}]` to be usable.

Comment: Are the shapes always circles?

Comment: Yeah - so I just want replacement for `rplot` that, apart from its speed, is indistinguishable from the above. But, if you have a more general solution, that's also welcome!

Comment: Simon, I just got done exercising, and my mind is cloudy.  You want to color the areas in which *n* or more circles overlap, with each discrete region colored differently.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes. Or, more accurately color the areas where exactly `n` circles overlap. If the fill is not completely opaque, then the places with more than `n` overlaps will be darker.

Comment: (still cloudy) If you don't color the areas where *more* than `n` circles overlap, wouldn't those areas be *white* instead of darker?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My bad! (I knew what I meant, just didn't say it correctly!)

Comment: A couple of possible methods come to mind.  Will you always draw the circles over the top of the fills?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, the circles are always going on top, which is why I suggested that a flood fill approach might work). Although, if you're going to approach it this way, it would be nice if the colors were close to the correct blends...

Comment: See my answer.  I am too tired to work though this right now, but it doesn't seem like a prohibitively difficult problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I previously posted this as an addition to my other answer. It's inspired by Simon's analytic approach, with some modifications to speed things up

```
intersect[n_, o_] :=
  With[{a = Pi/2 - (o-1) Pi/n},
   If[o-1 >= n/2, Return[{}]]; (* intersection is {} *)
   Polygon[
    Join[Table[{Sin[a] + Sin[phi], (-Cos[a] + Cos[phi])}, {phi, -a, a-2 a/10, 2 a/10}], 
     Table[{Sin[a] + Sin[phi], (Cos[a] - Cos[phi])}, {phi, a, -a+2 a/10, -2 a/10}]]]]

rplot2[n_, o_] := With[{pl = intersect[n, o], opac = .3, col = ColorData[1]},
  Graphics[{{Opacity[opac], 
     Table[{col[k], Rotate[pl, Mod[o - 1, 2] Pi/n + 2 Pi k/n, {0, 0}]}, {k, n}]},
    {Black, Circle[Through[{Re, Im}[Exp[I #]]]] & /@ (Range[n] 2 Pi/n)}}]
 ]
```

First of all, I'm using that for given value of `n` and `o`, the intersection region between the `i`-th and `i+o-1`-th circle is the same as the intersection region between the first and `o`-th circle except for a rotation over an angle `2 Pi (i-1)/n`, so it suffices to calculate the region once and use `Rotate` to rotate the region.

Also, instead of using a ParametricPlot to plot the intersection region, I'm using a `Polygon`  so I only need to calculate some points on the boundary which saves time.

The result for `GraphicsGrid[{{rplot2[3, 2], rplot2[5, 2]}, {rplot2[7, 3], rplot2[4, 1]}}]` looks like

[image: Intersecting circles revisited]

And the timings I get are

```
rplot2[10, 3]; // Timing

(* ==> {0.0016, Null} *)
```

compared to those for Simon's solution

```
rplot[10, 3]; // Timing

(* ==> {0.16519, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this

```
rplot[n_Integer, o_Integer] :=  Module[{centres, masks, opacity = .3, 
   colours, region, img, createmask},
  centres = Table[Through[{Re, Im}[Exp[I t]]], {t, 2 Pi/n, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n}];
  createmask[centres_] := Fold[ImageMultiply, #[[1]], Rest[#]] &@ 
     (ColorNegate[ Image[Graphics[Disk[#, 1], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
          PlotRangePadding -> .1], ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"]] & /@ centres);
  masks = createmask /@ Subsets[centres, {o}];
  colours = PadRight[#, Length[masks], #] & @ (List @@@ ColorData[1, "ColorList"]);
  region[img_, col_] := 
   SetAlphaChannel[ColorCombine[ImageMultiply[img, #] & /@ col, "RGB"], 
    ImageMultiply[img, opacity]];
  img = Fold[ImageCompose, #[[1]], Rest[#]] &@(MapThread[region, {masks, colours}]);
  Overlay[{img, Graphics[Circle[#, 1] & /@ centres, PlotRangePadding -> .1, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]}]
 ]
```

Then `GraphicsGrid[{{rplot[3, 2], rplot[5, 3]}, {rplot[7, 2], rplot[4, 1]}}]` produces something like

[image: cross sections of circles]

**Edit**

Moved previous edit to separate answer.

Comment: This looks good, but it doesn't work in version 7.  Is this possible without `SetAlphaChannel` and `Overlay`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It should be possible to replace `Overlay` with `ImageCompose`, but `SetAlphaChannel` is quite essential in my approach to colour the right regions and to get the blend right. I'll try to think of an alternative, though.

Comment: Please do not spend a lot of time on it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It works fine! It's about 10 times faster than the `RegionPlot` code and about 5 times slower than the `ParametricPlot` solution. Heike: Now that I've had time to parse the code, it's a nice approach. Thanks!

Comment: Nice edit, that code is fast! If you move it to a separate answer, I'll upvote you again and give you a big fat green tick!

Comment: @Simon now you're handing out parasites? :o)  (I learned it as *check mark*.)

Comment: Heike, I'd like to see a solution using `FilledCurve`, though it won't work in v7.

Comment: @Simon Thanks, I've posted it as a separate answer now. And I use ticks instead of check marks too, but I guess that's the British influence (in my case at least).

Answer (score 3):

Mr. Wizard made me realize that although I had an analytic form for the areas that I could use in `RegionPlot`, if I obtained a parametrized form for the boundaries, then I could use `ParametricPlot`. So, let's do that!

The i<sup>th</sup> (`i=0,...,n-1`) circle is parametrized in the complex plane by
`Exp[I t] + Exp[2 i Pi I / n]` for `t` in `[0, 2 Pi]`.

We can solve to find the intersection of the `i`<sup>th</sup> and the `(i+o-1)`<sup>th</sup> circles, where `o` is the number of overlaps, as in the original code of the question. This gives the points at

```
point[n_, o_, i_] := {Cos[(2 i Pi)/n] + Cos[(2 Pi (i + o - 1))/n], 
                      Sin[(2 i Pi)/n] + Sin[(2 Pi (i + o - 1))/n]}
```

Now we can parametrize the arcs going from the origin to a `point[n,o,i]` and reflect them across the line going from the origin to a `point[n,o,i]`. Interpolating between the two with a parameter `s` gives the parametrized regions

```
area[n_, o_, i_, t_, s_] := With[{a = 2 Sin[((2 + n - 2 o) (1 - t) )/(2 n) Pi], 
   b = (2 - 4 i + 2 t + n t - 2 o (1 + t))/(2 n) Pi, 
   c = ((2 + n - 2 o) (1 - t) - 4 i)/(2 n) Pi}, 
   {a (s Cos[b] + (1 - s) Sin[c]) , -a (s Sin[b] - (1 - s) Cos[c])}]
```

Then we can define

```
rplot[n_Integer, o_Integer] := ParametricPlot[Evaluate[
  Table[area[n, o, i, t, s], {i, 0, n - 1}]], {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1},
  Mesh -> False, MaxRecursion -> 1, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> 2.1 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  Epilog -> {Table[Circle[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 1], {t, 0, 2 Pi (n-1)/n, 2 Pi/n}],
    Red, Point[Table[point[n, o, i], {i, 1, n}]]}]
```

And `GraphicsGrid[{{rplot[3, 2], rplot[5, 3]}, {rplot[7, 2], rplot[4, 1]}}]` produces

[image: graphics grid]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I just needed the right hint (thanks for that) and a dinner break!

Answer (score 1):

### Analytic method

If the circles are always arranged in an even ring with as shown, there should be an analytic solution for the circle-circle intersection.  I would start with the number of degrees between each circle as laid out on the ring.

I shall explore this method as time allows.

### Raster method

1. Binary rasterize a series of disks in the correct locations
2. Assign unique power-of-2 values to each raster in place of ones
3. Add arrays
4. Compute unique set of overlaps from the value at each point in the totals array
5. Map correct colors onto resulting array and generate output

---

First rough pass of the raster method, simply as a proof of concept.  You can see that each region has a unique shading, which is just the sum of rasters at that point.

```
raster = 
  1 - First@Binarize@Rasterize@Graphics[#, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}] &;

disks =
  Table[raster @ Disk[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 1], {t, 2 Pi/#, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/#}] &;

n = 5;

array = disks[n] * 2^Range[0, n - 1] //Total;

ArrayPlot[array]
```

[image]

---

Second draft, adding colors.  It's still rather clunky.

```
n = 7; o = 2;

sets = Table[
   NestList[RotateLeft, PadLeft[Table[1, {o + i}], n], n - 1],
   {i, 0, n - o}
   ];

colors = NestList[
   Mean /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] &,
   List @@@ Take[ColorData[4, "ColorList"], n],
   n - o
   ];

rules = Append[Rule @@@ Flatten[{sets, colors}, {{2, 3}}], _ -> {1, 1, 1}];

Replace[Transpose[disks[n], {3, 2, 1}], rules, {2}] // Image
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not experienced at working with rasterized images, which is why I posted the question.

Comment: As for the analytic method, isn't that what my `RegionPlot` expression does? I guess I/you could also create parametrized curves and send it to `ParametricPlot` or to generate `Polgon`s. That might work - just need to calculate the intersection points and then switch between the standard circle parametrizations at those points.

Comment: @Simon, I am going to add a very basic example of the raster method in a minute.  RegionPlot just maps out a function space more than anything, as far as I can recall; it is not actually solving an intersection equation.